# \mathnormal bold in LaTeX

Tags: latex

How do I write this type of mathematical letter in LaTeX? I have tried `\mathnormal` but I can not make it bold.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the exact same type of bold and cursive x, then you can use `$\boldsymbol{x}$`. However, if all you want is a bold (but upright x), you can use `\mathbf{ }`.

By the way, if you are having to write a bunch of these, then I usually define a shorthand command:

```
\newcommand{\+}[1]{\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
```

which you can then write your example as:

```
$\+x_1, \+x_2, \ldots, \+x_n$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\boldsymbol{x}_{1}, \boldsymbol{x}_{2}, \dots ,\boldsymbol{x}_{3}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]